# Adding delimited text file PyQGIS WKT (pto1 pto2, pto3, pto4)

Tags: pyqgis

I have a tab separated text file

```
N_linea Punto1  diametro SDR    wkt_geom
```

The WKT contains expressions like this:

```
MultiLineString ((415120.8792 1126811.8435, 415124.8703 1126802.8395))
```

I have built the following expression:

```
fn4="file:///E:\DOCS\Manolo\Senara\SIG\Python\ejemplo1.txt?delimiter=%s&wktField=%s&useHeader=no&crs=epsg:5367&decimal=%s"%("\t","wkt_geom",".")
vlayer = QgsVectorLayer(fn4,'ejemplo1','delimitedtext')

# Compruebe si la capa es válida 
if not vlayer.isValid():
     print ( "Capa no cargada" )
```

But its doesn't work.

Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to make a few changes:

1. Use a double backslash when specifying the tab delimiter e.g. `"\\t"`
2. `useHeader=no` should be `useheader=no`
3. Single backslashes in your file path will cause problems since a backslash is an escape character in Python. Either use single forward slashes or double backslashes.

Try with the line below:

```
fn4 = "file:///E:/DOCS/Manolo/Senara/SIG/Python/ejemplo1.txt?delimiter=%s&wktField=%s&useheader=no&crs=epsg:5367&decimal=%s"%("\\t","wkt_geom",".")
```